# how to get an array response of jdbc request in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Example I have my JDBC Request and the response is like:

```
X     Y     Z
a1    b1    c1
a2    b2    c2
a3    b3    c3
a4    b4    c4
a5    b5    c5
.     .     .
.     .     .
.     .     .
```

How can I get all the value of x, y and z?

then I have HTTP request and I'm going to assert if all the response is matched to the data selected from JDBC.

example response:

```
{
    {
        "x":"a1",
        "y":"b1",
        "z": "c1"
    },
    {
        "x":"a2",
        "y":"b2",
        "z": "c2"
    },
    {
        "x":"a3",
        "y":"b3",
        "z": "c4"
    },
    {
        "x":"a4",
        "y":"b4",
        "z": "c4"
    },
    {
        "x":"a5",
        "y":"b5",
        "z": "c5"
    },
    {
        "x":"a6",
        "y":"b6",
        "z": "c6"
    },
    {
        "x":"a7",
        "y":"b7",
        "z": "c7"
    },
    {
        "x":"a8",
        "y":"b8",
        "z": "c8"
    },
    .
    .
    .                     
    .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [JDBC Request sampler documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request):

> If the Variable Names list is provided, then for each row returned by a Select statement, the variables are set up with the value of the corresponding column (if a variable name is provided), and the count of rows is also set up. For example, if the Select statement returns 2 rows of 3 columns, and the variable list is A,,C, then the following variables will be set up:
>
> ```
> A_#=2 (number of rows)
> A_1=column 1, row 1
> A_2=column 1, row 2
> C_#=2 (number of rows)
> C_1=column 3, row 1
> C_2=column 3, row 2
> ```

So given you provide "Variable Names" as `X,Y,Z` you should be able to access the values as `${X_1}`, `${Y_2}`, etc.

[image: JDBC Variable Names]

See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) for more detailed information on working with JDBC Test Elements results and result sets.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the "Variable Names" field and also declare a result variable name as shown below.

[image: JDBC ReqestSampler config view]

Then you can access them using the _1 _2 method. Please find below the sample code that you can use in the beanshell post processor.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser;
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;
import net.minidev.json.JSONArray;

ArrayList items = vars.getObject("result1");


for ( int i = items.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    JSONObject jsonitemElement = new JSONObject();
    jsonitemElement.put("x", vars.get("x_" + (i + 1)));
    jsonitemElement.put("y", vars.get("y_" + (i + 1)));
    jsonitemElement.put("z", vars.get("z_" + (i + 1)));
    log.info(jsonitemElement.toString());
}
```

Since you are getting these values as the response from the response payload of the HTTP request, you should add the code to parse that JSON response in an assertion or post processor and compare it with the elements from the above sample code.

A point to note - Different applications send the target JSON in any order. So, there is no guarantee that the HTTP response will always send the response as A1,B1,C1 - A2,B2,C2 etc. It can send them in any order starting with A5,B5,C5 etc. It is better to then use a hashmap or write your array comparison to ensure that your result set completely matches the HTTp response.