# How to pass variables from sampler1 response to sample2 request in Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm looking for a solution for the same kind of situation provided in [how to get an array response of jdbc request in jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831871/how-to-get-an-array-response-of-jdbc-request-in-jmeter) but need to provide the variable as user defined.

Let's say I would like to pass `A1 = dan` and my user defined variable is `name = 'dan'`. I'm defining it in user defined variable.

```
if(x==name)
then
{vars.put("Y")
}
```

then this should pass variable as `${Y}` in the http sampler.

Is there a way to do this?.

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare anything via [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables), if you have variable `A1` as a result of the `Sampler1` you should be able to access it as `${A1}` in the `Sampler2`

[image: JMeter Variables across samplers]

Moreover, you should not be updating the value of a User Defined Variable as it will not be propagated anywhere else:

> Note that all the UDV elements in a test plan - no matter where they are - are processed at the start.

So I can see 2 use cases:

1. Your 2 samplers are in the same [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group). In this case you don't need to do anything, variable will be normally accessible by other samplers
2. Your 2 samplers are in different Thread Groups. In this case you will need to convert the variable into a JMeter Property using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty). The property can be accessed in other Thread Groups using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P). If your test logic is more complex, i.e. 2nd thread group should not run Sampler2 unless the variable is available - in this case you will need the [Inter-Thread Communication](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) Plugin (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager))

Comment: same thread group.
Well, value we get for a1 is not always same and a1 will be some generated # and b1 value is a name/code that I know. The value I want might going into  a3 for second run. So if I define b value then it should get a value and pass into another sampler. trying to retrieve one var passing another. So basically need to give has if(a_n="user defined) { vars.get(b_n)}.         New to this not sure how to do?. Thanks in advance.